# Macro runs, but doesn't actually work in 'Print Preview' mode

Tags: excel, vba

The code below adds an item to Excel's cell menu (accessed by right-clicking a cell), whenever a single cell in column A is selected.

It works as expected when viewing the document in Normal view, but when Print Preview is selected, the code runs, but the item never gets added to the cell menu.

To test this out, simply paste the code below into Sheet1's code window within the visual basic editor, then right click a cell in Column A. You will see a new menu item with a smiley face icon at the top of the context menu.

Now switch to Print Preview, and right click a cell in Column A. The menu item does not appear. If you set a breakpoint in the `AddToCellMenu_Comments` sub, then you can see the code is running, but it has no effect!

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 1 Then
            AddToCellMenu_Comments
        Else
            DeleteFromCellMenu
        End If
    Else
        DeleteFromCellMenu
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub AddToCellMenu_Comments()
    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
    Dim MySubMenu As CommandBarControl

    ' Delete the controls first to avoid duplicates.
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu

    ' Set ContextMenu to the Cell context menu.
    Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

    ' Add one custom button to the Cell context menu.
    With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=1)
        .FaceId = 59
        .Caption = "Configure Comments"
        .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub DeleteFromCellMenu()
    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
    Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl

    ' Set ContextMenu to the Cell context menu.
    Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

    ' Delete the custom controls with the Tag : My_Cell_Control_Tag.
    For Each ctrl In ContextMenu.Controls
        If ctrl.Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag" Then
            ctrl.Delete
        End If
    Next ctrl

    ' Delete the custom built-in Save button.
    On Error Resume Next
    ContextMenu.FindControl(ID:=3).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

***JUST TO ADD***
It also works in 'Page Layout' view. It's just the 'Print Preview' view that doesn't work.

Comment: There are two Cell menus so you need to alter your code to loop through the commandbars and add the control(s) to both of them.

Comment: @Rory. Thanks! Do you know what the second cell menu is called? The one I'm currently targeting is simply called `Cell`.

Comment: They are both called "Cell" - that's why you have to loop through all the commandbars and test the name.

Comment: Ok. I just enumerated all their names and I see exactly what you mean! Thanks again :0)

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 Really nice code by the way... Just wondering, where do you run the code for your custom control button when it's clicked in the menu?

Comment: @dwirony in between the lines `With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=1)`, and `.FaceId = 59`, you should add the following `.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "wsJobs.AddClientOrContract"` where `wsJobs` is the name of the worksheet containing the sub you want to run, and `AddClientOrContract` is the name of the sub you want to run. See the following link for more information - https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4375-excel-add-button-macro-to-right-click-menu.html